# SOAP Client On Dreamhost

Tags: php, soap, dreamhost

I really really need help.  Been trying to get this on and off for over a month now and still no luck.

I need to enable the soap php extension in Dreamhost.  Preferrably the native PHP soap, but something like NUSOAP will do too, just have no idea how to make it happen and how to use it.

Someone please help.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dreamhost do not by default provide `SoapClient` . But then you can always install your own version of PHP with the required libraries. Check http://wiki.dreamhost.com/Installing_PHP5

Answer (score 4):

Dreamhost includes SoapClient in their build of PHP 5.3.  You can switch to php 5.3 in the domain settings of your dreamhost control panel.